# MySQL Subquery Syntax + ZF2 Syntax

Tags: mysql, sql, select, zend-framework2, subquery

I have a football database with 10k+ rows. My goal is to select one player by his id and get all other players which are in the same league or club or have the same nationality.
My query so far is the following:

```
 SELECT * 
 FROM  `characteristics` 
 WHERE `nation` = (SELECT `nation` 
                   FROM `characteristics` 
                   WHERE `id` = "1") 
 OR    `club`   = (SELECT `club` 
                   FROM `characteristics` 
                   WHERE `id` = "1") 
 OR   `league`  = (SELECT `league` 
                   FROM `characteristics` 
                   WHERE `id` = "1")
```

I think the query doesn't work as I expected, because it will return 1434 rows. For example: `Nation = Argentina`, `League = BBVA`, `Club = FC Barcelona` will return together something about 1500+ rows.

Maybe you guys can help me with this subquery.

Another problem is the subquery syntax in ZF2. I found something here on stackoverflow, but I can't figure the syntax out where to put something.

EDIT: example of db data

```
id  firstname lastname age height nation     club          league
1   Lionel    Messi    28  170 cm Argentina  FC Barcelona  Liga BBVA
```

Comment: `characteristics`  is your players table ? could you show some data ?

Comment: Yes it's the name of the table. Example of data edited.

Comment: Do you get duplicates? You could try adding `DISTINCT` to your query...

Answer (score 0):

I can't answer regarding ZF2 as I am not working with this.

For your SQL question, I think you are looking for this :

```
SELECT C1.`id` as playerid, 
       C1.firstname as playerfirstname, 
       C1.lastname as playerlastname, 
       C2.* 
FROM  `characteristics` C1
INNER JOIN `characteristics` C2 
   ON ( C1.`nation` = C2.`nation` OR 
        C1.`club`   = C2.`club`   OR
        C1.`league` = C2.`league` )
WHERE C1.`id` = "1"
```

The idea is to retrieve the player from `characteristics` (alias `C1`) and then to JOIN the table `characteristics` again (alias `C2`) on the columns you specified.

Comment: Thanks for response, but when I use your query I will get the same amount of rows like above.